# Android Java: Choose dynamically a subtype class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, singleton

I have two classes (D and E) that have some common methods, the only difference is that
D instantiates a singleton (A) and E instantiates another singleton(B).

E inherits from D and since the methods exec the same code, I' d like to check in D if I should create A or B singleton for not rewriting in E the same code of every common method...

A and B have inheritance from C abstract class...

Any advices?

Thanks in advance...

```
//Check subtype
if ....
  A field = A.getInstance().getMethod();
else...
  B field = B.getInstance().getMethod();

field.set...
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the nicest solution would be to create an interface `C` and to make `A` and `B` implement this interface.  Declare the methods you want to use in `D` and `E` in the interface, e. g.:

```
public interface C {
    public void setThatImportantField(String value);
}
```

In `D`, add a method that creates the singleton instance:

```
protected C createSingletonInstance() {
    return new A();
}
```

In `E`, override this method and return a new instance of `B`.  In your initialization code in `D`, you now may use the methods defined in the interface:

```
protected void initSingleton() {
    C singleton = createSingletonInstance();
    singleton.setThatImportantField("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best advice I can give: read good books on OO design.

More to the point, inheritance should only be used when the true relationship between the father and son is a "is a" relationship. Code reuse can be achieved in other ways (e.g. a utility class used by both).

You can create a method in D that only creates the singleton and use it. Implement it in one way in D and override it with another implementation in E.

Answer (score 0):

Make the method that creates the singleton parametric and use just a single class (instead of D and E) to do the job would not work?